# Adding classes for active progress on one page checkout

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, onepage-checkout

I would like to have an active class for the current step I am in in the progress.phtml file but there seems to be no way of knowing which step I'm in inside that file. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an idea for this but I don't know prototype so I'm stuck. I go to accordion.js where the steps are actually changed and opened on the main accordion and go to this section:

```
openSection: function(section) {
    var section = $(section);

    // Check allow
    if (this.checkAllow && !Element.hasClassName(section, 'allow')){
        return;
    }

    if(section.id != this.currentSection) {
        this.closeExistingSection();
        this.currentSection = section.id;
        $(this.currentSection).addClassName('active');

        //This is my line, it doesn't work:
        $$('#step-'+this.currentSection).addClassName('active');
        var contents = Element.select(section, '.a-item');
        contents[0].show();

        if (this.disallowAccessToNextSections) {
            var pastCurrentSection = false;
            for (var i=0; i<this.sections.length; i++) {
                if (pastCurrentSection) {
                    Element.removeClassName(this.sections[i], 'allow')
                }
                if (this.sections[i].id==section.id) {
                    pastCurrentSection = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
```

See my line there?:

```
 $$('#step-'+this.currentSection).addClassName('active');
```

I added ids to the progress.phtml items to match that but I keep getting

```
TypeError: $$(...).addClassName is not a function
```

It seems I was out of the scope there. I added an event trigger there and then a listener to change the classes and it worked for me.

Comment: It appears this isn't working because accordion.js can't reach the sidebar. Thanks for the downvote without leaving any constructive comments...

Comment: Not a bad idea - but it doesn't cover the change links in the progress sidebar as discussed in our chat session.

Comment: Could be the beginning of another modular solution.

Answer (score 1):

In the default Onepage Checkout theme, progress.phtml gets loaded on every AJAX call, and has a number of checks if it is complete, if so it adds a class:

```
    <?php if ($this->getCheckout()->getStepData('billing', 'is_show')): ?>
    <?php if($this->getCheckout()->getStepData('billing', 'complete')): ?>
        <dt class="complete">
            <?php echo $this->__('Billing Address') ?> <span class="separator">|</span> <a href="#billing" onclick="checkout.accordion.openSection('opc-billing'); return false;"><?php echo $this->__('Change') ?></a>
        </dt>
        <dd class="complete">
            <address><?php echo $this->getBilling()->format('html') ?></address>
        </dd>
    <?php else: ?>
        <dt>
            <?php echo $this->__('Billing Address') ?>
        </dt>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

What you're then asking is to style the last item in progress.phtml that has the class `complete`. For that we'll use jQuery or Prototype to add the appropriate class:

**Prototype:**

```
$$(".complete").each(function(x) { $(x.lastChild).addClassName("active"); });
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(".complete:last-child").addClass("active");
```

Comment: Good approach but this won't work if the customer goes back a step if he made a mistake or wanted to change something like the shipping address :(

Comment: If the customer goes back a step, add in the appropriate class remove on the onclick event.

Comment: Same with 'edit' links in the progress bar itself.

Comment: then you also need to remove the rest of the active classes then? isn't this a bit messy? how can I do this at the same time that the list on the left changes classes? that's also done in accordion.js but I don't know prototype.

Comment: As you note, the issue at hand is that 'going backwards' doesn't re-render anything - it's expanding an accordion. You can be more specific in your use of the `each` function above using the progress block's class - `opc-block-progress`

Comment: I don't quite understand that last thing you said. What I meant is how do I include the change of class on progress.phtml when the events openSection and closeSection occur inside accordion.js and if that is right or wrong

Comment: I understand - I will edit my answer to provide direction, however if further discussion is needed we can start a chat.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8548/discussion-between-elaine-marley-and-philwinkle)

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like that

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.button, .section').click(function(){

            if(jQuery('#opc-billing').hasClass('active')){
                jQuery('#billing-progress-opcheckout dt').addClass('orange');
                jQuery('#shipping-progress-opcheckout dt').removeClass('orange');
                jQuery('#shipping_method-progress-opcheckout dt').removeClass('orange');
                jQuery('#payment-progress-opcheckout dt').removeClass('orange');
            }else if(jQuery('#opc-shipping').hasClass('active')){
                jQuery('#billing-progress-opcheckout dt').removeClass('orange');
                jQuery('#shipping-progress-opcheckout dt').addClass('orange');
                jQuery('#shipping_method-progress-opcheckout dt').removeClass('orange');
                jQuery('#payment-progress-opcheckout dt').removeClass('orange');
            }else if(jQuery('#opc-shipping_method').hasClass('active')){
                jQuery('#billing-progress-opcheckout dt').removeClass('orange');
                jQuery('#shipping-progress-opcheckout dt').removeClass('orange');
                jQuery('#shipping_method-progress-opcheckout dt').addClass('orange');
                jQuery('#payment-progress-opcheckout dt').removeClass('orange');


            }else if(jQuery('#opc-payment').hasClass('active')){
                jQuery('#billing-progress-opcheckout dt').removeClass('orange');
                jQuery('#shipping-progress-opcheckout dt').removeClass('orange');
                jQuery('#shipping_method-progress-opcheckout dt').removeClass('orange');
                jQuery('#payment-progress-opcheckout dt').addClass('orange');

            }



        })

    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace last `<dt>` tag with

File : template\checkout\onepage\progress\billing.phtml

Add below code just after to "this.currentStep = section;" line (line number 35)

file : skin\frontend\jumex\default\js\opcheckout_rwd.js

```
$j('div dt').removeClass('current');

if( $j('#'+section+'-progress-opcheckout').length >0){
$j('#'+section+'-progress-opcheckout dt').addClass('current');
}
```

Now you can see every active step have apply current class to `<dt>` tag so you can set it as active.